# Swift Add codable to array of codable

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array

I looking to convert a row of SQlite to JSON array.

Example:

```
{
    "0": {
      "room_id": "5034"
    },
    "1": {
      "room_id": "5199"
    },
    "2": {
      "room_id": "5156"
    }
}
```

Swift4 code:

```
typealias Rooms = [String: Room]

struct Room: Codable {
    let roomID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case roomID = "room_id"
    }
}

    var rooms = [Rooms]()


        for room in try (db?.prepare(isco_room_time))! {
            let export: Room = Room(roomID: room[room_id])
            rooms.append(export)
        }
```

My error (on line rooms.append) :

Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Room' to expected argument type 'ViewController.Rooms' (aka 'Dictionary')

Comment: What exactly does `db?.prepare(isco_room_time)` return?

Comment: `var rooms = [Rooms]()` is the same as saying `var rooms = [[String: Room]]()`, but you're then trying to append an instance of `Room` to it, which is obviously incompatible.  Change `var rooms = [Rooms]()` to `var rooms = [Room]()`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this?

```
typealias Rooms = [String: Room]
```

If you want an array of Codable objects you don't need the alias
Changing

```
var rooms = [Rooms]()
```

To

```
var rooms = [Room]()
```

Will work.

Comment: His JSON is not a `[Room]` (an array of `Room` objects), but rather it is a `Rooms` (a dictionary of `[String: Room]`, which is not the same thing. The text of his question says it's an array of `Room`, but the JSON itself is actually a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var counter = 0
var rooms = [String:Room]()
 do {

      guard let dbs = db else { return }
      let res = try dbs.prepare(isco_room_time)
      for room in res {
       let export: Room = Room(roomID: room.id)
       rooms["\(counter)"] = export
        counter += 1
     }
   }
  catch {
    print(error)
  }
```

Comment: And Rooms, where is? :)

Comment: what type of`dbs.prepare(isco_room_time)` ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan where is any explanation of your answer? Anybody can write "You can try"

Comment: @RobertDresler my answers are self descriptive , it's supposed that i speak to a developer not a beginner

Comment: @Sh_Khan do this, try this, use this. You've 38k of karma and does this make you good programmer? You have years of experience and does this make you good programmer? Maybe you have some knowleadge, but your ego is bigger than it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Since rooms is a dictionary you shouldn't use append

```
for room in try (db?.prepare(isco_room_time))! {
    let export: Room = Room(roomID: room[room_id])
    rooms[room_id] = export
}
```